# adding extra name to generated moc file

Tags: c++, qt4, cmake, ros

I have a strange problem that i couldn't find the answer, I've been writing a catkinized app with qt in ros hydro (catkin), some times after making my project by catkin_make it gives me a strange error, it is not constant maybe in 10 compiles i have 1 time this situation. also the program perfectly works in successful compile. the problem is that while qmake creating moc files, there is an extra name to my classes, the strange thing is that this name is not constant(two different names i've seen until yet) and this problem is not for all my classes and it is randomly in each occurrence for one of them!
I've wrote below just prototype of functions in two different compiles with this siutuation

```
    1-> static const uint qt_meta_data_ros__message_traits__JURSEGMainWindow[] ...
    2-> static const uint qt_meta_data_jur_gui_segmentation__JURGUIROSNode[] ....
```

as you see in first ros_message_traits and in second one jur_gui_segmentation (name of my package) is extra!

anybody has an idea! i appreciate it.

Comment: Are files being built in parallel with `-j`?  It's possible that most of the time all your files are compiled before the final link phase, and then every once in a while the final link phase starts before one or more parallel jobs finish their work.

Comment: yes, it is a cmake project that catkin macro for making run this command 'make -j4 -l4'. also when i compile it inside the qtcreator this problem have not been occurred even one time. another thing is that i found this that i've added to end of question, may be it helps.

Comment: If You'd provide minimal `CMakeLists.txt` which would have exactly the  same behaviour, it would help way more than these error.